# MySQL subquery as alias - unknown column error

Tags: mysql

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'expensetot' in 'field list'
```

Based on the query below, what is the best way to produce grandtotal without an error?

```
SELECT 
  table1.cost,
  (SELECT SUM(expense) FROM table2 WHERE table2.key=table1.id) as expensetot
  (table1.cost+expensetot) as grandtotal,
  table3.label
FROM
  table1
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.key=table1.id
WHERE
  table1.saledate>SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
ORDER BY grandtotal
```

Comment: What are the relations between the three tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use alias  in select clause you must repeat the code

and you missed  a comma before table1.cost + ...

and in subselect the outer table are not in scope  so you should use a proper join with subquery for sum

```
 SELECT 
    table1.cost, 
    t.expensetot,
    table1.cost + t.expensetot as grandtotal,
    table3.label
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
  select table2.key, sum(table2.expense) expensetot
  from table2
  group by  table2.key
) t on t..key=table1.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.key=table1.id
  WHERE
    table1.saledate>SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  ORDER BY grandtotal
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, was trying to avoid the double query

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would help

```
      SELECT 
      table1.cost,
      (SELECT SUM(expense) FROM table2 WHERE table2.key=table1.id) as expensetot,
      (table1.cost+(SELECT SUM(expense) FROM table2 WHERE table2.key=table1.id)) as grandtotal,
      table3.label
    FROM
      table1
      LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3.key=table1.id
    WHERE
      table1.saledate>SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    ORDER BY grandtotal
```

or you can read about user variables in queries: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: trying to avoid double queries. Already tried this with success but inefficient. I should have stated that in my question.